# Qt Creator error endless loop

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to create a project which was developed by someone working in a different country and timezone I keep getting the following error in my console. He had mentioned this problem is because of the Data/Time being different from his computer to mine. I'm not sure if that is true, if it is, there has to be a solution for that without having to change my computer time to match his. I'm not sure what else to post that would be helpful in trouble shooting this, if there is just let me know and I'll update. I'm a bit new to C++/Qt Creator. Why is this happening. It seems to never finish, it just endlessly prints this to the console.

**Compile Output Console**

```
Running steps for project Nexus...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" -o Makefile ..\Nexus\Nexus.pro
C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" -o Makefile ..\Nexus\Nexus.pro
C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" -o Makefile ..\Nexus\Nexus.pro
C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" -o Makefile ..\Nexus\Nexus.pro
```

**General Message Output Console**

```
Warnings while parsing QML type information of C:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/qml:
<dump of C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\qml>:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.
<dump of C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\qml>:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.
```

**Pro file**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-02-29T21:37:32
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

include(core/core.pri)
include(node/node.pri)
include(librarybox/librarybox.pri)
include(blockeditor/blockeditor.pri)
include(propertyeditor/propertyeditor.pri)
include(lib/lib.pri)


TARGET = Nexus
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h


FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    virtualnamepropertyitem.ui

RESOURCES += \
    nexus_resources.qrc

RC_FILE = nexus.rc
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? That qmake is called multiple times?

Comment: You can try to change your date/time to test if it's really related.

Comment: @maddin45 how can i find where in the code it's calling qmake?

Comment: Check the modification time of your `.pro` file. It might be from the future.

Comment: @Zeta the time in the file is from the future, how can i modify the file to fix that?

Comment: You must travel back to the future, Marty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen if your `.pro` file (or any other file) has a timestamp from the future. The `Makefile` generated by `qmake` contains a rule that will generated the `Makefile` anew when its older than the `.pro` file. Since the new `Makefile` is *still* older than its counterpart from the future, this will go on till you actually reach the correct time.

There are two ways to get rid of this behavior:

1. Wait till the `.pro` file's timestamp is in the past (not recommended)
2. Edit the `.pro` file. Even a trivial edit like a new comment should be enough.

Comment: He can even undo the change and save again after this.

Comment: i tried this and it stll loops through the QMake process

Comment: @JojOatXGME: Yeah, anything. On unix-like systems  `touch *.pro` would be enough, but I'm not sure of the Windows counterpart.

Comment: @JokerMartini: You did close QtCreator inbetween, right?

Comment: @Zeta close it after I change the pro file? No i didn't do that.

Comment: How can i try this solution? https://forum.qt.io/topic/51402/solved-qmake-stuck-in-infinite-loop/3

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with latest version of QtCreator (3.6.1 with Qt 5.6.0).

Answer proposed by "Zeta" did not help.

Disabling "Shadow build" in project options fixed the problem for me. That's a good workaround.

Finally shorten file names (somes where huge) to fix the issue:

- Shortened project names (.pro) (file name and path, removed a few caracters)
- Shortened resources names (.qrc) (file name and path, removed a few caracters)

Issue then disappeared (even with shadow build, it's probably related as shadow-builds are using an output folder with a very long name).

There's apparently a bug when file paths are too long (>~170, found [a post on a forum reporting that](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59963-a-simple-project-with-quot-Infinite-building-quot)).

An alternative is also to change the pattern used by QtCreator for shadow builds. This can be modified from the QtCreator options and you can then make the name shorter, this is another way to quickly and easily fix the issue.

Comment: When using **shadow build** `qmake` does indeed create very long paths: `build-<App name>-<Platform>_Qt_<Version>_MinGW_<Architecture>-<Build type>` though I am surprised that this error never occurred on Linux and did on Windows. I'm using Qt 5.7. Your solution did solve my problem but it creates a small chaos inside the source directory(ies) since without shadow build everything is put in there.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Changing `build-<App name>-<Platform>_Qt_<Version>_MinGW_<Architecture>-<Build type>` to something shorter like for instance `<App name>-mybuild_<Architecture>-<Build type>` from Qt options may let you continue using shadow builds and fix the issue.

Comment: @Gojir4: Agree ;-)

Comment: @jpo38 Yes, it allows you to use shadow build however it puts a huge restriction on the file structure of large and complex projects. The issue is in the Windows even in 2017 (almost 2018 now) still has one too many archaic mechanisms in its belly.

Comment: This appears to  still be in an issue in 2020 due to Windows maximum path length of 260 characters uppsetting other applications. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52242

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script that loops through recursively through all the files of the project and simply just resaves the files. That updated the timestamp and corrected the QMake Infinite loop. It now compiles correctly.

Comment: Mind sharing it?  I could write one too (or that directly changed the timestamp), but if you could post yours it might save myself and other some time / trouble.